# prediction score in decision tree

Tags: cart, boosting, gradient

In this article 
http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model.html
under the caption Tree Ensemble, the diagram shows 3 prediction score under the 3 nodes, +2, +0.1, and -1. How were these numbers derived? The article gave no clue.

Comment: I believe they are just for illustration.  You compute the predictions from the regression trees in a gradient booster in the same way as any other regression tree: as the mean of `y` over all the training samples share the same leaf node as the given sample point.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353406/what-are-the-final-predictions-in-tree-based-models .. please answer here if you found it